# find duplicates in SQL: but I get only one row instead of 2?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

with the following query I get only one row but I should have 2:

```
SELECT * FROM `acl` GROUP BY `vara`, `varb`, `varc`, `vard`, `vare`, `varf`, `varg`, `varh`, `vari`, `varj`, `vark`, `varl`, `varm`, `varn`, `varo`, `varp`, `varq`, `varr`, `vars`, `vart`, `varu`, `varv` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Here are my duplicates:
access-list REUTERS_access_in extended permit icmp any host DAF-SUPE-1 log interval 600

access-list REUTERS_access_in extended permit icmp any host DAF-SUPE-1 log interval 600

I retrieve only the 1st row.
How can I modify my query to get both rows?

Many thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query as you've written it will return all of your duplicates, but will not display the multiple rows because you are grouping by all to determine your duplicate rows.  SQL will never display the dups like this.  There's no reason to, because they're dups.  Now if there are columns that are different, that are not in the "GROUP BY" then you just have to include them in the SELECT statement, and then SQL will display them.

What you can do to see how many duplicate rows you have for a particular GROUP BY, you can return the count as part of your select, like this...

```
SELECT count(*) count, `vara`, `varb`, `varc`, `vard`, `vare`, `varf`, 
       `varg`, `varh`, `vari`, `varj`, `vark`, `varl`, `varm`, `varn`, 
       `varo`, `varp`, `varq`, `varr`, `vars`, `vart`, `varu`, `varv` 
FROM `acl` 
GROUP BY `vara`, `varb`, `varc`, `vard`, `vare`, `varf`, `varg`, `varh`, 
         `vari`, `varj`, `vark`, `varl`, `varm`, `varn`, `varo`, `varp`, 
         `varq`, `varr`, `vars`, `vart`, `varu`, `varv` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks, but... it doesn't change anything: I still have only 1 row displayed and no "count" information. I want to see as much rows as I have duplicates (if I have 2 rows the same, I want to see them both). Could you help me ?

Comment: Reread my entire answer.  You cannot display the rows that are exact duplicates since you most likely have all of your table columns in the "GROUP BY" clause.  SQL will see no reason for that.  You use the "Count(*) count" in your SELECT clause so you can see how many rows you have.

Comment: But I don't see any count information. I don't have a column named "count" with a value (here should be 2).

Comment: Then you didn't run the query I posted in my answer.  If you did, it would give you a "count" column in the first position, which would tell you how many rows you have.

Comment: I did run the query you posted. Here are my columns: ID  vara  varb  varc  vard  vare  varf  varg  varh  vari  varj  vark  varl  varm  varn  varo  varp  varq  varr  vars  vart  varu  var  There is no count. OK, I have to say that I run this query in a PHP script. Could it be a issue ?

Comment: Your select clause should look like this... 'SELECT count(*) count, `vara`...'

Comment: Yes, PHP script may be the problem in that you are most likely viewing the results as a subset of the actual query.  What you need to do is run the query in some form of query analyzation tool.  For instance if your database is MSSQL, then you would use SSMS to run the query.  If you are running a MySQL Query, then you can use the MySQL Workbench and/or Navicat.

Comment: You should always develop your query in an analyzation tool and before consuming the query in your application.